# Why isn't my custom view drawing the foreground elements?

Tags: android

I'm stepping through "Professional Android 4 Application Development".  I'm working on the "ToDoList" example in chapter 4, and to the point of implementing a custom view for the list item. When I run my version of the app, the custom view renders its background color, but the margin line and the text don't appear to render.  I've compared my version against the version from the code bundle, and I only see what seem like inconsequential differences, but there must be something subtle that is different.

I obviously want to fix the problem, but something like this is a better lesson on how to figure out what's wrong, but I just don't see it.

I wish I could just zip up the two apps and attach them here, but that doesn't appear to be an option.  I did upload my sample app to a shared Google Drive folder, which is included [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzByqRAfzsn7dTBMOTFZZWpxZnc/edit).  I believe I've made it public so that other people can download it.

If someone reports that they can't get to it, I guess I'll just try pasting in the relevant source files here.

Comment: Just a note: it would be better to post the relevant code snippet here and explain the problem faced if you want more people to look at your issue and offer help. Expecting others to have read the book or to go through your entire source code would be a little too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...and I only see what seem like inconsequential differences, but
>   there must be something subtle that is different.

There is a difference that is quite important. In your `init` method you initialize the float `margin` variable like this:

```
margin = myResources.getColor(R.color.notepad_margin);
```

But, from looking at your code(where you draw the lines) the `margin` variable seems to be the point at which you draw  the vertical lines(in your case margin will be something big and out of the screen). Shouldn't this be:

```
margin = myResources.getDimension(R.dimen.notepad_margin);
```

Also, you may want to increase the stroke width to see those lines:

```
linePaint.setStrokeWidth(3.0f);
```